# PHP adding to sessions

Tags: php, session, xampp

I am making an online quiz, in this quiz, one question is asked at a time. If the answer is correct, I want to add that point, to the total score earned. I want the $_SESSION to show how many points the user has earned so far. The code I have so far is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz_questions WHERE Question='$question' AND Answer='$answer'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows != 0){

    $score++;
    $total_score += $score;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['score'] = $total_score;

} else {
    echo "Incorrect";
}
  }
```

I already have $score equal to 0 to start in the beginning of the code. Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: is there a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start(); // should be at the beginning of your script(s);
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) { $_SESSION['score'] = 0; }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz_questions WHERE Question='$question' AND Answer='$answer'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($num_rows != 0){

    // $row = fetch row to get the actual score for this question, if answered right?
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    //$score++; ??????
    //$total_score += $score;
    $_SESSION['score'] += $row['score_index'];
    //$_SESSION['score']++; // or just this, dunno
    echo 'Your current score is: '.$_SESSION['score'];
}
else {
    echo "Incorrect";
}
```